# Can't escape $ in regex using stringr::string_extract

Tags: r, regex

In the string I am trying to extract the `0.4%` that comes after `12 month(s)\n$500`

I search for `12 month(s)\n$500` and then grab number dot number that comes after.

From [here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html), "To match a literal “$” or “^”, you need to escape them, $, and ^."
But when I do that, I get the error:

`Error: '\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?<=12 month(s)\\n\$"`

What am I doing wrong?

```
x <- "Term Minimum investment Rate Interest type Get this GIC\n3 month(s)\n$500 0.15% Simple\nChoose this GIC\n6 month(s)\n$500 0.25% Simple\nChoose this GIC\n9 month(s)\n$500 0.30% Simple\nChoose this GIC\n12 month(s)\n$500 0.40% Simple\nChoose this GIC\n18 month(s)\n$500 0.50% Simple\nChoose this GIC\n18 month(s)\n$500 0.50% Compound\nChoose this GIC"

as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=12 month(s)\\n\$500)\\d\\.\\d{1,}"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape with double backslash in R. (`\\`). Also you need to escape opening and closing round brackets (`()`).

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(x,"(?<=12 month\\(s\\)\n\\$500\\s)\\d\\.\\d{1,}"))
#[1] 0.4
```

In base R with `sub` :

```
as.numeric(sub('.*12 month\\(s\\)\n\\$500\\s(\\d\\.\\d{1,}).*', '\\1', x))
```

Comment: Although my question is basic I don't think it's reasonable that I would have searched for the moderator's suggestion. I had forgotten that brackets need to be escaped. Thank-you @Ronak Shah for the speedy response.